# Regular expression for DateTime in this format 01/23/2013 10:25

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I need to tweak a regular expression listed below to make sure the data is validate accordingly to this format:

01/23/2013 10:25

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}")]

[RegularExpression("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date")]
```

The current regular expression it seems does not take account of HH and MM

Could you please give me an hit? Thanks

Comment: Why would you validate datetime using Regex? You are using wrong tool. Although it might work, but it clearly becomes complex and unreadable. You should better use `DateTime` parsers, appropriate in the language you are using.

Comment: Which tool do you suggest me? I need a straight forward solution to implement data annotation on a DateTime field in MVC 3 web app.

Comment: @GibboK.. Well, I'm not the `DotNet` guy. So, can't tell you about any tool. But certainly you would find one by a little only search.

Answer (score 1):

For `HH:mm`, you can use this regex: -

```
(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])
```

So, adding it to your regex, it would become: -

```
"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9] (?:(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]))$"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately using your regex the validation fail with a date in this format 01/23/2013 10:38  what could be the problem?

Comment: @GibboK. Sorry. I forgot to group the two parts of `HH:mm`. Now it would work. You can try it.

Comment: it seems that does not work, maybe the problem it is in some other place... anyway man thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this may be it will usefull for this case [Try This](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

OR
you should create your own validator (inherit BaseValidator) and use DateTime.TryParseExact to check that the value can be converted to DateTime.

Comment: have you seen [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565012/how-to-write-a-regex-for-mmddyyyyhhmmss) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717638/need-to-validate-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-tt-in-javascript)