# How to apply regular expression for Date format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS am/pm in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reg-expressionvalidator

I have a TextBox where I am taking input from as user as **`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`**. Now, I want to validate it with a regular expression. I'm not sure how to apply the expression. I have attached my code as well.

```
  <tr>
      <td style="width: 30%" class="EcommLabel">
          Date From
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70%" class="EcommLabel">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" CssClass="EcommNormalTextBox" runat="server">
          </asp:TextBox>MM/DD/YYYY<br />

      <%-- <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regDateFrom" ValidationExpression="^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ValidationGroup="Promotion" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>

      <asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="rvDateFrom" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" MaximumValue="3000/12/31" MinimumValue="2000/1/1" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Promotion" />
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: How about custom DateTime parsing instead of regex?

Comment: No actually i need to be done using regular expression only..

Comment: Why? I'm genuinely curious why you could only use regular expressions...

Comment: What about different cultures?

Comment: @wonderb0lt See the `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`?

Comment: ...Yes? I'm sure there's something similar for dates in ASP? :)

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the regular expression that you have?  Are you getting errors, or results that you don't expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression for dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360599/regular-expression-for-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm)

Comment: @wonderb0lt Fair enough! I don't think there *is* a date validator, hence the need to use the regular expression one to get all the client/server-side validation for "free".

Answer (score 1):

use this expression "(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})" like

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regDateFrom" ValidationExpression="(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})"
                                    ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ValidationGroup="Promotion" runat="server"
                                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Date"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Also see the following stackoverflow questions:
[How to write a regex for MM:DD:YYYY:HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565012/how-to-write-a-regex-for-mmddyyyyhhmmss) 
[MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM date validation regular expression in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375711/mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-pm-date-validation-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change of your regular expression would do it.

Use the following regular expression

> ^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$

It will validate the value **01-12-2011 19:59:59**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regDateFrom" 
  ValidationExpression="^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$"  
  ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ValidationGroup="Promotion" 
  runat="server"
  ErrorMessage="Invalid Date">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a date picker where I am taking input from as user as MM/DD/YYYY. I want to validate it with a regular expression. Find Below code it might be help full.

```
expression = "^([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])/([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))/[0-9]{4}$";
```